# Copy charts on each worksheet and paste them to each slide respectively

Tags: excel, vba, charts, copy, powerpoint

My code now is pasting 1 chart onto 1 slide. How do I make it paste all of the charts on Sheet1 (2 charts in Sheet1) to Slide1 and all of the charts (2 charts in Sheet2) on Sheet2 to Slide2, and so on... I tried increasing the `count` but the code fails.

```
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptCL As PowerPoint.CustomLayout
Dim pptShp As PowerPoint.Shape

Dim chtt As Chart
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

'Optimise execution of code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Get the PowerPoint Application object:
Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
ppt.Visible = msoTrue
Set ppTPres = ppt.Presentations.Add

'Get a Custom Layout:
For Each pptCL In ppTPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    If pptCL.Name = "Title and Content" Then Exit For
Next pptCL

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i = 1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count
        Set pptSld = ppTPres.Slides.AddSlide(ppTPres.Slides.Count + 1, pptCL)
        pptSld.Select

        For Each pptShp In pptSld.Shapes.Placeholders
            If pptShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderObject Then Exit For
        Next pptShp

        Set chtt = ws.ChartObjects(i).Chart
        chtt.ChartArea.Copy
        ppt.Activate
        pptShp.Select
        ppt.Windows(1).View.Paste
    Next i
Next ws

'Optimise execution of code
Set chtt = Nothing
Set pptSld = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: What error code do you get?

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov The code I posted has no problem working, it is just not working up to what I want. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly when changing the count but I got this error: Integer out of range. 2 is not in the valid range of 1 to 1

Comment: When you get an error message, click on the Debug button and you'll see the highlighted line of code that caused it. Currently, you're creating 1 slide for each chart, because the Set pptSld line is inside the chart counting loop. Move it up one line to create 1 slide per worksheet. But you have code in there that does nothing, like the 3 lines below 'Get a Custom Layout. And you don't need to be selecting anything, this will work faster and better using the ranges instead of selections.

Comment: To make this work as you describe, it would be best to create custom layouts with varying numbers of chart placeholder. Get the number of charts on the worksheet, pick a layout with the same number of placeholders and paste the charts to that. Otherwise, all the pasted charts will tend to pile up on each other.

Comment: @JohnKorchok thank you, I managed to copy the respective charts